# Using optional parameters in Umbraco 7 Urls

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Am new to using Umbraco. I need to create Urls with an an optional parameter on the end e.g.

```
mysite.com/people/john
mysite.com/people/jane
etc
```

however by default Umbraco appears to require a separate page for each person. Is there a built method in Umbraco that will allow me to define the last part of the Url as an optional parameter or do I have to write a custom route for it?

Thanks

Comment: You may already know this, but by default Umbraco will capture an optional parameter at the end of a path and apply a template having that alias to the current page. For example, if you have a template called `template-123`, the url `mysite.com/people/template-123` will render your `people` content using that template. To me, this is one of the more useful development features in Umbraco, but if you don't think you'd ever use it, then IIS URL rewrite would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Use IIS URL Rewriting to rewrite your URLs under the hood and rewrite `/people/john` to `/people/?person=john` say. Then you can pick up the person from the query string on the page.
2. Write a custom URL Finder that looks for the URLs and does some stuff under the hood, like get the people page, and then set a context item with the person name in for you to use in your views etc.
3. You could write a custom route for it. Custom routing in Umbraco is slightly different to in normal MVC. Here is a blog post detailing how you can do it: http://shazwazza.com/post/custom-mvc-routes-within-the-umbraco-pipeline/